# How to Pass the Current ID as the position in recycler View?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

> I am using the Youtube API to play Videos in a recyclerView
>
> But i have to HARDCODE the videoID everytime, also I have created a list of videoID, how to pass the respective videoID instead of hardcoding.
>
> Here is my VideoActivity.java :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel> myModelList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    myModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    myModelList.add(new com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel("hMy5za-m5Ew"));
    myModelList.add(new com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel("unU9vpLjHRk"));
    myModelList.add(new com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel("k9zTr2MAFRg"));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,myModelList));
```

> Here is MyAdapter Class :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 Context context;
List<com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel> myModelList;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel> myModelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myModelList = myModelList;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel myModel = myModelList.get(position);
    final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Error : " , String.valueOf(errorReason));
        }
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.show();
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
    };
    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(myModel.getId());
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured OnIntitialisationFailure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Details : " + youTubeInitializationResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myModelList.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
    protected ImageView playButton;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        playButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context, YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), "unU9vpLjHRk", 100,
                true,
                true);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

> Here is my Model Class :

```
public class CustomModel {

String id;

public  CustomModel(){

}
public CustomModel(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

> How to pass the Current VideoId from the list instead of hardcoding a single value as you can see in OnClick() in Adapter Class ?

Comment: implement  OnClickListener on this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: But why can't i do this way, i mean what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: `String id = myModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click event on the onbindViewHolder() like

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < CustomAdapter.ViewHolder > {
    Context context;
    List < com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel > myModelList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List < com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel > myModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myModelList = myModelList;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final com.devapps.masjid.CustomModel myModel = myModelList.get(position);
        holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLister() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context,
                    //here you can get the api key
                    YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), mymodel.getId(), 100, true, true);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error : ", String.valueOf(errorReason));
            }
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.show();
                youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        };
        holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(myModel.getId());
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
            }
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured OnIntitialisationFailure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Details : " + youTubeInitializationResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myModelList.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
        YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
        ImageView playButton;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            playButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);

            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
            youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx Awesome answer